# JSP IntelliJ java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea

I'm trying to call my TestRunner class located in my src folder from my index.jsp file (located in my web folder). My TestRunner class calls methods of classes in different modules. When I run the test runner class's main method, everything is working fine. However, whenever I start up the Tomcat server and the TestRunner class's methods are called, I keep getting the NoClassDefFoundError whenever it reaches the point of execution where these classes from other modules are referenced. Everything is compiling correctly and, as I said, the main method of the TestRunner class is running perfectly on its own. What could the issue be?

Comment: "whenever I start up the Tomcat server and the TestRunner class's methods are called" --- Why would you run tests on tomcat? Tests should be isolated from production code.

Comment: Sorry, 'TestRunner' is perhaps a poor name for my application. Essentially, the application will return to me arraylists that I am using to create an html table.

Comment: @c.kent That might be because at runtime you are missing those classes (but you have them available at compile time). Are you using any building tool like maven?